# TextBox validation works even when it is disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have done validation for textbox to check whether they are empty, but even when text box are disabled, the condition is being checked and as per validation message is being displayed

> text box cannot be empty

```
if ((txt1Yes1.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || txt1Yes2.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
         MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All The Details");
```

I have written this and this is to be checked only if text box are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra `if` condition whether the `TextBox` controls are disabled or not.

```
void validateDetails()
    {
        if (txt1Yes1.Enabled && txt1Yes2.Enabled)
        {
            if ((txt1Yes1.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || txt1Yes2.Text.Equals(string.Empty)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All The Details");
            }
        }
    }
```

For checking whether the `TextBox` controls are disabled or not(toggling), I have used the `CheckedChanged(...)` event of the `checkBox` control.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tbox = control as TextBox;
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    tbox.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                    tbox.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
[for disable the required field validator on the Disabled controls.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/427158/How-to-Disable-required-field-validator-when-contr)